# HTML5 pattern attribute being ignored

Tags: html, validation

Just trying to make a field that only accepts 8-digit numbers and every browser lets it pass with any number of digits.

```
<form>
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]{8}" required>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here am not seeing the problem with my pattern.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mavelo/pen/VVZvoP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `<input type="number">` elements do not support use of the `pattern` attribute for making entered values conform to a specific regex pattern.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Pattern_validation

Comment: Thanks. Knew I had to be missing something. Seems odd they allow pattern for `input type="email"` but not `input type="number"`. Oh well, I'm validating server-side, but intercepting with a pattern would have been nice. The `min` and `max` attributes are a viable alternative to lack of pattern support for now :)

Comment: Decided to shim it up with jQuery and add pattern support :P With honorable mention of course ;) https://www.robertmullaney.com/2018/11/01/add-pattern-support-html5-input-type-number-jquery-shim/ Thanks again!